# Using npm to install packages gives command not found?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Using npm to install packages, I can never use their cli. For instance, install grunt-cli, avn, nvm, etc. and running

```
npm install -g avn avn-nvm avn-n    
avn setup
```

Results in command "avn" not found. I don't know if this is a pathing issue, but my PATH is:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/share/npm/bin

I am using OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path does not include where the node_modules you're installing globally exist. You need to include the bin path for the modules:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/node_modules/.bin
```

Comment: In Ubuntu, it is `/usr/local/lib` instead of `/usr/lib`